# Difference between JavaScript methods structure

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

What is the difference between this method structures/callings?
I often see different method structures and I can not understand what the benefits of each are.

```
var obj = {
    some_method: function(){
        return 'This works';
    }
}

var Obj2 = function(){
    return {
        some_method: function(){
            return 'This works too';
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj.some_method());

var obj3 = new Obj2();
console.log(obj3.some_method());
```

Both of them return what they should, here's [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRBY/), but in what case I should use each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one resembles a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), I.E. you cannot have multiple objects of same type but with distinct state. Like it's only possible to have one actual animal in your entire application instead of many.

A more practical example, consider this page. There are multiple `Post`s, each with their own state (What `Comment`s they have, what text they have, are they currently being edited and so on). If you just did `var post =` then that means there can only be one post.  I suspect you will probably have some ad-hoc jQuery to manipulate multiple posts in that singleton but then you are not doing object oriented modeling of the problem anyway.

---

The second one is using constructor function incorrectly, the created objects will not be instances of `Obj2` but `Object`. You would use a constructor like:

```
function Obj2() {
   //initialize fields here
}

Obj2.prototype.someMethod = function(arg) {
     return this.state + arg;
};
```

The reason returning object literal works in a constructor is that a constructor
is allowed to return objects of any type. But it doesn't make sense to make a constructor
only to return `Object`s.

You typically need `Object`s only for grouping related *static* functionality together (behavior, but no prolonged data)
or as a dictionary/map/associative array (data but no behavior).

Comment: The second one is some form of module pattern maybe? Of course it doesn't have to be called with `new` in this case.

Comment: @FelixKling In module pattern you would immediately invoke it as it doesn't make sense to require clients to call a function for nothing. You should be able to just `var module = require("module");` instead of `var module = require("module")();`

Comment: I see. I never really used it, so it just looked similar in my eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you are calling `obj.some_method()`. `some_method` is a function, nested as a property of `obj`. This pattern is one way of namespacing.

In the second case, you are creating an object, using `Obj2` as a constructor. However, instead of returning an instance of `Obj2`, you returned an object which has the same structure as the previous example's `obj`. This will give you erroneous results from `instanceof` tests, since `new Obj2` should return an instance of itself, which your code isn't doing.

Comment: Writing a function like that is often done when you want to build an _Object_. The capital letter and `new` does suggest use as a constructor, but (this example) works the same if called as a normal function